# Is it possible to log transfer all my variables when doing linear regression?

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics, logarithm

I am currently handling data where all the variables are right-skewed.
I would like to log-transfer all the x and y variables, and if I do, the results are great. But I am making a table for the descriptive statistics and the table does not look neat because all the variables' names are 'Log ...'.

Anyways, is it possible to log-transfer all my variables when I'm doing linear regression? And if it is, should I attach the descriptive statistics table that describes the log transferred variables or the original variables?

Comment: To answer the second question we'd need to know what you wish the table to achieve ( what's it for?). Can you include both untransformed and transformed values?

Answer (score 3):

For the descriptive statistics, it might make sense to report the geometric mean, and perhaps comparable statistics for e.g. standard deviation, confidence intervals, standard error.  Also presenting plots with a log y-axis, or log-log axes.  Note that geometric means are traditionally used in some fields for some measurements, for example by regulation for bacteria counts in water in the U.S.A. ... A different approach would be to report the summary statistics included in the "five number summary":  median, along with 0th, 25th, 75th, 100th percentile. ... My personal opinion is that reporting summary statistics on the log scale of the variable isn't generally helpful for the reader.

Comment: +1 I agree completely that "reporting summary statistics on the log scale of the variable isn't generally helpful for the reader."

Comment: Thank you :) I might as well report the descriptive statistics of the regular data. My variables are all highly skewed and by reporting the mean and median, I am planning to justify why I log-transformed all the variables. Will this be a possible strategy?

Comment: @kyrhee , yes, I think it makes sense to report the statistics on the original scale.  Mean and median, maybe other percentiles, maybe all presented as box plots.

Answer (score 2):

It you take the logarithms (assuming all the values are positive) then you have a different model

so instead of something like $$y=b_0 +b_1x_1 +b_2x_2+\varepsilon$$

you get something like $$\log_e y=b_0 +b_1\log_e x_1 +b_2\log_e x_2+\varepsilon$$

which is equivalent to something like $$y=e^{b_0}\,x_1^{b_1}\,x_2^{b_2}\,e^\varepsilon$$

If this makes sense, then you should

- explain what you are doing
- note that the descriptive statistics are reporting in terms of the second expression
- consider whether you want to report point estimates and confidence intervals for $b_0$ or for $e^{b_0}$, and be clear about the choice you have made

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) This is exactly what I am trying to do. All the variables are log-transformed. Because all of the data are highly skewed. Can you explain more about the last sentence? What does it mean by reporting point estimates and confidence intervals to be clear?

Comment: @kyrhee If you are reporting an estimate for $b_0$ from the second model as say $4 \pm 1$, i.e. a confidence interval of $[3,5]$ then your central estimate of $e^{b_0}$ in the third is $54.6$ with a confidence interval of $[20.1,148.4]$